# Hide and show a dropdownlist based on checkbox selection

Tags: asp.net, vba

So far this is what i have tried and cant get it to work. I had formatted slightly different earlier and the code worked but would only hide/show the the dropdownlist I wanted when i made another selection on my form. I am looking for a way to write this code so that dropdownlist is made visible or non visible as soon as the checkbox changes from false to true and vice versa

```
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlcars" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" Visible="False">
                    <asp:ListItem>Please select a model</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="18295">Impreza</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="26595">WRX</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="21595">Crosstrek</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlpromocars" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" Visible="False">
                    <asp:ListItem>Please select a model</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="25395">BRZ</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="24995">Outback</asp:ListItem>
```

Spring Promotion

```
Protected Sub chkpromo_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles chkpromo.CheckedChanged


    If chkpromo.Checked = True Then
        ddlcars.Visible = False & ddlpromocars.Visible = True
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If chkpromo.Checked = False Then
        ddlcars.Visible = True & ddlpromocars.Visible False 
 Exit Sub
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: did you try with javascript? or jQuery?

Comment: Sorry I am a programming pleb. All i know is I'm using visual studio.

Comment: Pls, edit your question and add your aspx/html code for dropdownlist "ddlcars" and "ddlpromocars", and chkBox "chkpromo"

Comment: I believe that is the info that you wanted. I have to make essentially a mock subaru dealership page for an assignment and I'm trying to make the dropdownlists visible and non-visible based on the checkbox selection so that I can prevent user error of a person checking that a car is part of a promotion that it is not actually part of.

Answer (score 0):

Remove Autopostback="True" for chkpromo, ddlcars and ddlpromocars to avoid postbacks

Remove Visible="False" for ddlcars and ddlpromocars to write html but hide it with css class.

Remove OnCheckedChanged="chkpromo_CheckedChanged" for chkpromo to avoid postbacks

And try

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>YOUR TITLE</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function SetDdls(isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
                document.getElementsByName('ddlcars')[0].style.display = 'none';
                document.getElementsByName('ddlpromocars')[0].style.display = 'block';
            } else {
                document.getElementsByName('ddlcars')[0].style.display = 'block';
                document.getElementsByName('ddlpromocars')[0].style.display = 'none';
            }
        }
    </script>
    <style>
        /*only for hide  some element */
        .hide {
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="chkpromo" OnClick="SetDdls(this.checked);" Text="Click Me" />  <%--OnClick fires javascript function "SetDdls"--%>
            <hr />
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlcars" runat="server" >
                <asp:ListItem>Please select a model</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="18295">Impreza</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="26595">WRX</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="21595">Crosstrek</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlpromocars" runat="server" CssClass="hide"> <%--Hide by default unchecked--%>
                <asp:ListItem>Please select a model</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="25395">BRZ</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="24995">Outback</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>

        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And finally delete from code behind Sub "chkpromo_CheckedChanged".

Answer (score 0):

### So i changed my code to this and it works but the dropdownlist wont update until i change another control on my web form. Is there a way that I can make the ddl change upon me clicking on the checkbox

Protected Sub chkPromo_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles chkPromo.CheckedChanged

```
    If chkPromo.Checked = True Then
        ddlpromocars.visible = True
        ddlcars.Visible = False
    End If
    If chkPromo.Checked = False Then
        ddlpromocars.Visible = False
        ddlcars.Visible = True
    End If
End Sub
```